# WHERE clause in sub-query

Tags: sql, select, subquery, where-clause, having-clause

Following SQL query:

```
select *  from er_101
 where cd_relnaam IN ( 
     select cd_relnaam 
     from er_101 
     group by cd_relnaam 
     having count(*) > 1)
 AND ld_relopdrachtgever = '1'
```

Though I need to have that sub query also limits on `ld_relopdrachtgever = '1'`
How is that possible with an HAVING statement?

Comment: Please give us the structure of your Table and what you want to achieve because it's not very clear right now.

Comment: The subquery isnt specified with an value like the main query:
AND ld_relopdrachtgever = '1'

I also needed that In my subquery otherwise I get results in my resultset that have multipli values but not with ld_relopdrachtgever equel to 1

Comment: The subquery limit you can do by adding `WHERE Id_relopdrachtgever='1'` before grouping by `cd_relnaam`.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `WHERE` in sub-query.

```
SELECT * FROM er_101
 WHERE cd_relnaam IN ( 
     SELECT cd_relnaam 
     FROM er_101 
     WHERE ld_relopdrachtgever = '1'  <--You can add WHERE clause before GROUP BY
   --^^^^^----
     GROUP BY cd_relnaam 
     HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
 AND ld_relopdrachtgever = '1'
```