# use a result from a query as a condition to another query

Tags: sql, database, oracle11g, subquery

i have a query that return a single codeNumber
i want to use that code to as a where condtion in another query to return the name field

this is the query

```
select e1.SuperCODE
from (select EE.* from Table1 e , Table2 ee 
where ee.CODE=e.CODE 
and ee.TYPE_CODE=13 
and E.ID=2089 
order by E.FROM_DATE) e1
where  rownum = 1;
```

the result from this query 490

i want to take this result
to put it in this query

```
select name from Table2 (the same table above)
where Table2.code= THE RESULT FROM ABOVE QUERY //490
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WHERE clause in sub-query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13085483/where-clause-in-sub-query)

Comment: Left justified SQL is so hard to read...

Comment: `select name from Table2 (the same table above)
where Table2.code= (youroriginalqueryhere)`

Answer (score 1):

Did you try just using `=` with a subquery:

```
select t2.*
from table2 t2
where t2.code = (select e1.SuperCODE
                 from (select ee.*
                       from Table1 e join
                            Table2 ee 
                            on ee.CODE = e.CODE 
                       where ee.TYPE_CODE = 13 and
                             e.ID = 2089 
                       order by e.FROM_DATE
                      ) e1
                 where rownum = 1
                );
```

Note the use of proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.